# Basic python error with importing module - getting modulenotfound error

Tags: python

I'm doing something basic with python, and I'm getting a pretty common error, but not able to find exactly what's wrong. I'm trying to use a custom module (built by someone else). I have the folder structure like this:

[image]

There is the `test` folder, and I have a file `testing.py` within that:

[image]

The contents of `testing.py` is:

```
from util import get_data, plot_data
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  print(x)
```

When I run this file, using python testing.py, I get this:

[image]

I went through the other questions that speak about paths, and this looks fine, so not sure what I am missing here. My environment is setup using conda, and the environment is active.

**EDIT**

As per @allan-wind, I made the relative edit, which got me past the error, but now getting different errors:

I tried the relative import, and it got past that error, but then it is now throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 190, in get_context
    ctx = _concrete_contexts[method]
KeyError: 'fork'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grade_analysis.py", line 21, in <module>
    from grading.grading import (

  File "E:\_Repo\GT\CS7646\mls4tsp23\grading\grading.py", line 15, in <module>
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 246, in set_start_method
    self._actual_context = self.get_context(method)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 238, in get_context
    return super().get_context(method)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 192, in get_context
    raise ValueError('cannot find context for %r' % method)
ValueError: cannot find context for 'fork'
```

`

Comment: We prefer text to screenshots as the former is searchable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to specify how to find modules:

1. Use a relative [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html):

```
from .util import get_data, plot_data
```

2. Set the environment variable PYTHONPATH includes the directory where you module resides.
3. See [sys.meta_path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path)

Comment: I tried the relative import, and it got past that error, but then it is now throwing a different error (see edit)

Comment: It appears to be an issue with util.py that you haven't shared with.  I suggest you accept the best answer for your first problem and provide a [mre] for the new problem.  The context thing could perhaps be because you use fork when it should be spawn (see https://github.com/beancount/beangrow/issues/11)

Answer (score 0):

Just place utils in the same folder as your testing.py and the python interpreter you put that directory in your path. Other solutions would be to place utils in a directory that is already in your path, since if thats not the case, you cant import from "above" the current directory